# In a Row, Find the the column where the immediate next column is empty

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I need to find out the last existing value, and set that value to 0.
If the entire row outside of id are Null, just leave that row intact.

So for Example the Inputs are:

```
╔════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦
║ ID ║ Col1 ║ Col2 ║ Col3 ║
╠════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬
║  1 ║ 100  ║ 100  ║ 100  ║
║  1 ║ 20   ║ 200  ║ NULL ║
║  1 ║ 30   ║ NULL ║ NULL ║
║  1 ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ 
╚════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩
```

I want to process the row and return:

```
╔════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦
║ ID ║ Col1 ║ Col2 ║ Col3 ║
╠════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬
║  1 ║ 100  ║ 100  ║ 0    ║
║  1 ║ 20   ║ 0    ║ NULL ║
║  1 ║ 0    ║ NULL ║ NULL ║
║  1 ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ 
╚════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩
```

Comment: Can the number of fields always be four (including the `ID`) or will the number of columns vary?

Comment: Also, is the value of `ID` meant to be always `1` in your data and output?  Can there be other `ID`'s?  If so, should we limit the output to just `ID = 1`?

Comment: Do you want an `update` or `select`?

Comment: How do you determine the order that the values are displayed in?

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply, So I prefer a select and the values inside the table comes from another database, they come like this. as for ID, they are just examples, they are actually unique identifiers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT ID,
       CASE
           WHEN Col1 IS NULL THEN
               NULL
           WHEN Col2 IS NULL THEN
               0
           ELSE
               Col1
       END AS Col1,
       CASE
           WHEN Col2 IS NULL THEN
               NULL
           WHEN Col3 IS NULL THEN
               0
           ELSE
               Col2
       END AS Col2,
       CASE
           WHEN Col3 IS NULL THEN
               NULL
           ELSE
               0
       END AS Col3
FROM tblTable;
```

I tested the above against a sample dataset created using the following script...

```
CREATE TABLE tblTable
(
    ID     INT,
    Col1   INT,
    Col2   INT,
    Col3   INT
);
INSERT INTO tblTable ( ID,
                       Col1,
                       Col2,
                       Col3 )
VALUES ( 1, 100, 100, 100 ),
       ( 1, 20, 200, NULL ),
       ( 1, 30, NULL, NULL ),
       ( 1, NULL, NULL, NULL );
```

The desired output was achieved.

The logic that I used was that if the value of a `Col` is `NULL` then it should be left unchanged in the output.  Otherwise, if the value of the next `Col` is `NULL` then the last existing value for that record has been found and should be set to `0` in the output.  Otherwise, the `Col` being examined is not the last existing value and thus should be left unchanged in the output.

With the final `Col` you do not need to test for what the value of the next `Col` will be.

If you have any Questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There is the brute force way:

```
update t
    set col1 = (case when col1 is not null and col2 is null and col3 is null then 0 else col1 end),
        col2 = (case when col1 is not null and col2 is not null and col3 is null then 0 else col2 end),
        col3 = (case when col1 is not null and col2 is not null and col3 is not null then 0 else col3);
```

However, the need to do this suggests that the columns are inter-related.  That, in turn, suggests that the values should be stored on separate rows rather than in separate columns.